# Which Star Wars comics narrates the Mandalorian war?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, mandalorian

I'd like to read about the whole Mandalorian war, but I'm completely ignorant on SW comics and which of them constitutes canon.

Should I just read all those in [this](http://www.swbooks.co.uk/timeline/old-republic.htm) timelime from "      Knights of the old Republic" up to "Jedi Civil War"?

Are some comics not included in the list?

Comment: I believe that the Mandalorian Wars are not canon, but Legends. So there may not be any (Disney) canon comics that cover it.

Comment: @Adamant [Actually...](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandalorian-Jedi_War)

Answer (score 2):

The war is covered in the 'Knights of the Old Republic' series, but it's mostly a background event. The rise of Revan is mentioned, and Malak appears a couple of times, but the war itself isn't directly part of the plot until the ['Knights of the Old Republic: War'](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic:_War) miniseries set shortly afterwards